# TextBox = Select From Sql convert datetime to Date

Tags: c#

Hi i want to bring a value from sql into a textbox as date. I'm using this code:

```
 SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select top 1 expirationdate from incomes where memberid='0' or memberid = '" + textBox22.Text + "' order by expirationdate  DESC", con);
 textBox17.Text = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString("d/M/yyyy");
```

I get an error: no overload for method “ToString” takes 1 arguments

Comment: `ExecuteScalar` returns an object.  Make sure you cast it to the appropriate type (`DateTime`?). then you'll be able to invoke the overloaded `ToString(s)`.

Comment: Never. Never. Never concatenate input into SQL.

Comment: Good ole Bobby Drop Tables is gonna visit you. https://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to first convert it to DateTime. Also use sql paramaters to avoid sql injection.

```
 SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select top 1 expirationdate from incomes where memberid='0' or memberid = @memberId order by expirationdate  DESC", con);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("memberId",textBox22.Text);
    var result = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
    textBox17.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(result).ToString("d/M/yyyy");
```

Comment: Can you write me an example?

Comment: I don't know about this answer. Seems to me like, depending on what the `ExecuteScalar` call returns, you're converting a date to a string, back to a date, and back to a string again.  Too many hoops.

Answer (score 1):

First: use parameters

Second: cast the value from `ExecuteScalar` before trying to format it

```
int memberId = int.Parse(textBox22.Text); // or whatever
DateTime expiry;
using(var command = new SqlCommand(
    "select top 1 expirationdate from incomes where memberid='0' or memberid = @memberid order by expirationdate  DESC", con))
{
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("memberid", memberId); // again, about 20 ways to do this
    expiry = (DateTime)command.ExecuteScalar();
}
textBox17.Text = expiry.ToString("d/M/yyyy"); // or whatever
```

or with a tool like "dapper":

```
int memberId = int.Parse(textBox22.Text); // or whatever
var expiry = con.QuerySingle<DateTime>(
    "select top 1 expirationdate from incomes where memberid='0' or memberid = @memberid order by expirationdate  DESC",
    new { memberId });
textBox17.Text = expiry.ToString("d/M/yyyy"); // or whatever
```

Comment: @DiH see the edit; was meant to be `expiry.ToString()`